# MIMEのパース・作成をするおすすめのCommon Lispライブラリは？

Tags: common-lisp

Common Lispで[MIME](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipurpose_Internet_Mail_Extensions)のパース・作成をするライブラリでおすすめのものは何ですか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickdocsで検索すると、以下のライブラリがあるようです。

- [cl-mime](https://github.com/hanshuebner/cl-mime)
- [mime4cl](http://wcp.sdf-eu.org/software/#mime4cl)

また、汎用的なものではありませんが、HTTPの本文で使われるmultipart/form-dataのパースに限定すればfast-httpが使えます。

```
(ql:quickload '(:fast-http :cl-syntax-interpol :babel))
(syntax:use-syntax :interpol)

(let ((parser (fast-http:make-multipart-parser "multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x"
                                               (lambda (name headers field-meta body-stream)
                                                 ;; ここにcallback処理を書く
                                                 ))))
  (funcall parser (babel:string-to-octets #?"--AaB03x\r
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"field1\"\r
\r
Joe Blow\r\nalmost tricked you!\r
--AaB03x\r
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pics\"; filename=\"file1.txt\"\r
Content-Type: text/plain\r
\r
... contents of file1.txt ...\r\r
--AaB03x--\r")))
```